# Dropdown not validating at all and must be another value but 0

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I am trying to validate a dropdown which is created multiple times so I have used a class selection to find it through the code. But the validation is not working; the previous developer created the select in code behind which is listed in second code block. What I need is to make sure that any element but element 0 is selected when they click the submit button.

This is the button that uses the function

```
<asp:Button ID="ibutReturn" runat="server" Text="Return to Requested Uplifts" class="Uplifts_button_small" Visible="false"  />
```

Is it because `causevalidation = true` is missing? Sorry, I'm more used to .NET than jQuery

```
$(".ddlReason").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "0" && strMessage.indexOf('Reason Information') < 0) {
    strMessage += "Please Ensure All Reason Information is complete. \n"
    }
}
```

But the issue is the validation is not firing at all, even though it is in the document ready function. I know this is probably not the best way of handling this type of validation, but it's what I have to work with as they won't change just for a quick fix.

```
  strReasonDDL = ""
      ReasonURL = RowID & "_R1_"

      Reason &= "<select class=""ddlReason"" id=""" & Trim(oDataRow2("Product")) & """> "
      Reason &= "<option value=0>-- Reason --</option>"
      For Each oDataRow3 In oReasons.Rows
          If Trim(oDataRow3("rowid")) = Trim(oDataRow2("ReasonID")) Then
              Reason &= "<option selected=""selected"" value= " & ReasonURL & Trim(oDataRow3("rowid")) & ">" & Trim(oDataRow3("uplift_reason")) & "</option>"
          Else
              Reason &= "<option value= " & ReasonURL & Trim(oDataRow3("rowid")) & ">" & Trim(oDataRow3("uplift_reason")) & "</option>"
          End If
          Next
              Reason &= "</select>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using the Ready method to run custom validation, it should probably by done via the...

```
Page_ClientValidate();
```

...call in javascript.  You can also call...

```
Page_ClientValidate("MyValidationGroup");
```

...for validating only specific controls.  This CAN be called during Ready method, I think, though you may want to check the console output for any errors, it's been a while since I've done this.

This is of course used in conjuction with all the asp.net validation controls like this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="AnyOldId" ClientValidationFunction="MyJavascriptMethodName" ErrorMessage="Please enter a time" ControlToValidate="MyTextbox" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidateEmptyText="true ValidationGroup="MyValidationGroup"/>
```

Comment: as said they wont allow me to change the code drastic lots of sales go through site as is

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Ready method actually reaches where you expect?

Comment: It might be an idea to handle the `window.onload` handler instead of using the jQuery Ready method.  That's because it will wait until ALL content of the page is loaded.